# issues with CORS in .NET Core

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am making a form with a submit button and when I click it to send the informations to my database,I get this error in the console:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API LINK' from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I make the call to my API like this.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'API LINK',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(interventionData),
        headers: {
               "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
               "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE",
               "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
               "Accept": "application/json",
               "Content-Type": "application/json"
```

from what I understand, the CORS error is happening because I'm calling my API in my view and I should find a way to call it in my controller.

this is the button that calls my function in my view.

```
<button onclick="submitIntervention()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

CORS appears 2 times in my startup.cs file and I feel like I should add something to it

```
services.AddCors();


app.UseCors(builder => builder
             .AllowAnyOrigin()
             .AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader());
```

I'm new at this and not sure how I could make this call in my controller.  Thank you for any pointers.

**EDIT:**

after I fixed Cors in the Azure portal, I get this.

POST API LINK 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Is your view not also served from `https://localhost:5001`?

Comment: @gunr2171 That's the ASP.NET Core documentation. From what OP has said, they're using .NET Framework and therefore ASP.NET. OP, this is the correct documentation for ASP.NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors (please also note "Set the allowed origins").

Comment: thanks alot for your reply @Llama I looked into it and updated my question. should I try to add the information to the first AddCors in my startup file or the one that came by default. I added the first one in the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: Wait... you've tagged .NET but it seems like you're using .NET Core. In that case, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is the documentation you want.

Comment: You don't put cors headers on the request so all that JavaScript header stuff can be binned

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET Core and my api is deployed on Azure @CaiusJard

Comment: Personally I'd configure CORS in the azure management portal in that case.. Do you know if it's in-process or out-of-process hosting?

Comment: Once I modified Cors in the Azure portal I get a 405 not allowed error for my api call @CaiusJard

Comment: Can you show what you have configured?

Comment: `POST API LINK 405 (Method Not Allowed)`,can you share your api which is called by ajax?